# tkinter & python-requests: show files after download in file manager

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-requests

I have written a tkinter based program that fetches an image from link and saves it as name given by user. I want to open the image in file manager after download.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import requests

window = Tk()
window.title('Image downloader')
back_ground = "#2c2c2c"
c_white = "#ffffff"

def imageDownload():
   if link_image.get() != "" and save_image.get() != "":
      r = requests.get(link_image.get())
      with open(save_image.get(), 'wb') as img:
      img.write(r.content)
      messagebox.showinfo(save_image, "Downloading")
   else:
       messagebox.showinfo('error', "imagelink, or save as    name not found")

window.overrideredirect(False)
window.configure(bg=back_ground)
name_link = Label(window, text="Enter link", width=10, pady=3, bg=back_ground, 
                  fg=c_white)
name_link.grid(row=0, column=0)
link_image = Entry(window, bg=back_ground, bd=0, highlightcolor=c_white, fg=c_white)
link_image.grid(row=0, column=1, )
name_image = Label(window, text="Save link", width=10, pady=3, bg=back_ground, 
                   fg=c_white)
name_image.grid(row=1, column=0)
save_image = Entry(window, bg=back_ground, bd=0, highlightcolor=c_white, fg=c_white)
save_image.grid(row=1, column=1)
save_button = Button(window, text="Get", command=imageDownload, bg=back_ground, bd=0, 
                     width=6, highlightcolor=c_white, fg=c_white)
save_button.grid(row=2, column=0)
exit_button = Button(window, text="Exit", command=window.quit, bg=back_ground, bd=0, 
                     width=17, highlightcolor=c_white, fg=c_white)
exit_button.grid(row=2, column=1)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Show image in file manager?So do you want it show the image in a new window?Or the folder of the image path?

Comment: image path to show

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a description of what is wrong — i.e. what isn't working or isn't being done correctly.

Comment: Use `os.path.dirname` to get the parent directory,then use `os.system(f"explorer {path}")` to open it in default explorer.

Comment: thanks @jizhihaoSAMA